# Rselenium select dropdown menu

Tags: html, r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

Hi I am trying to use Rselenium to select a dropdown menu.

The field I want to click for the dropdown menu is Date Range so I look up in the html code (see picture below) and found

```
class="select2-choice"
```

to be the pointer so I invoke command to click on the dropdown menu

```
webElem <- rd$client$findElement(using = 'xpath',
                             value = '//*[@class="select2-choice"]')
webElem$clickElement()
```

[image]

Then I want to select "Custom" in the dropdown field so I look up in the html code (see picture below) and found it is under

```
select id="namedRange-3640"
```

and the option is

```
value="custom"
```

[image]

so I try to invoke Rselenium command again to click on this custom field

```
webElem <- rd$client$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//select[@id='namedRange-3640']/option[@value='custom']")

webElem$clickElement()
```

However there is no action in the webpage, there is no warning from the code either. I tried in other webpage with much simpler structure like W3C tutorial on dropdown menu and it works. However in this case it seems to be slightly more complicated, with something called ng-repeat which I have not come across before. Anyone know how to select the custom field?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be the solution.

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4445)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("your_web_site.com")

frame_ws<- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="iframeResult")
remDr$switchToFrame(frame_ws)

#You can replace "today" with all elements the list
option <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = 'today']") 
option$clickElement()
```

If you want to deep the argument you should visit [here](https://ropensci.org/tutorials/rselenium_tutorial/)

Comment: Hi SlowLearning thanks for your answer. I agree that this work with simple dropdown menu, i.e. select type menu but apparently select2 dropdown menu are much more complicated. Upon looking at the html whenever the dropdown menu is opened there is a change in the class "select2-drop" which from there change the options in the select field like the html code above. Here is the additional select2-drop class I am talking about. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq7Be.png found at the very bottom of the html. As you can see both are linked to id: "s2id_autogen5"